# Deploy python web server on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, websocket, webserver, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying an python web server on AWS now and I have a some question about it. I'm using websocket to communicate between back end and front end.

1. Do I have to use framework like django or flask?
2. If not, where should I put the index.html file? in other word, after deploying, how do AWS know the default page of my application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS doesn't "know" anything about your content. The webserver that you install will be configured to point to the "root" directory in which index.html (or something equivalent) should be.

Since it depends on which webserver (django, flask, Jinja etc) you install - you should lookup its documentation!